# How does [hist] from SMLib work in Pure Data?

Tags: puredata

I put the following message into a [hist 0 100 10] object (in SMLib):

```
0 1 2 3 3 4 5 5 5 6 7 7 7 7 8 9 10 11 11 11 11 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 67 99 100 107
```

I then hit 'absolute' and the following is output.

```
6 19 18 0 0 0 0 1 0 3
```

I was expecting it to count the occurrences of the numbers into even bins of size 10 but only six numbers are in the first bin, and the 67 is in the wrong bin!

I counted up how it's evaluated it and got the following:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4] = 6
[5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 13, 14] = 19
[15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23] = 18
[]   = 0
[]   = 0
[]   = 0
[]   = 0
[67] = 1
[]   = 0
[99, 100, 107] = 3
```

But..  I was expecting the following result.

```
16 14 13 0 0 0 1 0 0 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it!

I was using [hist 0 100 10] when I should have been using [hist 5 105 10]!